# Multiple angular request

Tags: angular

I am trying to access my server 5 times but on encountering an error I want to stop my subscription in angular. Below is my code in angular. Any help will be highly appreciated!

## My component.ts

```
private getImageUrl(deviceId: string){
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
      this.deviceService.getImageURL(deviceId,i)
      .subscribe((res)=>{
          console.log(res);
        }, error =>{
          console.error(error);

        });

      }
  }
```

## My device.services

```
public getImageURL(deviceId:string, imageId: Number): Observable<any>{
    return this.communication.sendApi(
      `resources/${deviceId}/images/${imageId}`,
      {method: 'get'}
    );
  }
```

Or maybe how to let my observable go to the next request only after completing the first request.

Comment: Are you using RxJS (before I submit a response that would feature it)? Because RxJS makes for very _readable_ code, that is also easy to tweak. But if not, it may be easiest to use the simple `toPromise` method and then use promise's `catch` method.

Comment: @Drei Yes! I am using RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the code below.

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

... code omitted

   from([1,2,3,4,5])
    .pipe(mergeMap((value) => this._http.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${value}`
    )
   ),
  )
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
     console.log(response);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
```